# Android Java Fragment Button save

Tags: java, android, button, save, fragment

I got 2 Fragments. In the first Fragment I got a button. 
How is it possible to duplicate the button on the second Fragment when the user click on it.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: First just to save a button from one fragment to another

Comment: give id as android:id="@id/firstFragmentButton" rather android:id="@+id/secondFragmentButton"

Comment: that does not help me

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by duplicating a `Button`? If it means creating a Button with the same text or other layout attribute, you can create a method in the second Fragment, like `createButton(String text, int color)`, to add the button dynamically. When the button is clicked, find the second Fragment, cast it to the class of second Fragment and call the createButton method.